# nmap сканирование списка диапазонов на определённый порт

Tags: сеть, сканирование-портов

Как в nmap просканировать список диапазонов из файла на наличие нужного порта, и положительный ответ записать в файл построчно (без лишнего мусора)?

Comment: Отметь правильный ответ ответом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
nmap -iL input.txt [--excludefile file.txt] -v[level_id] -p<PortN> -oX output.xml
```

в input.txt может быть все, что угодно, например, вот это:

```
myserver.com
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.2.1,2,3
192.168.3.0-200
```

если надо что-то исключить(хотя разумнее будет просто грамотно составить input файл), то опция **--excludefile** к вашим услугам.

в выходном файле будет содержаться результат сканирования в формате XML с минимальным "мусором".

Если "мусора" все еще будет много, то установите [необходимый уровень детализации](https://nmap.org/book/nping-man-output-options.html) с помощью **опции -v**

Comment: `код`nmap -iL диапазон1 -v [-2] -p 5900 -oX test.xml`код` Какой бы уровень я не выставил в выводе упорно <verbose level="1"/>

Answer (score 0):

Каждый результат в новой строке

```
nmap -p1337 -iL ip.txt -oG res.txt
```

А вобще парсеров xml чуть менее чем дохрена
так что лучше все таки(в том числе онлайн)

```
nmap -p1337 -iL ip.txt -ox res.txt
```

В ip.txt(форматов много практичиски любой формат диапазонов ip адресов подходит 1337 это порт):

```
127.0.0.1-255:1337
128.0.0.1-255:1337
```

Answer (score -2):

Никак. Нужно получить результат с тем что есть, потом при помощи консольных утилит для работы с текстом сделать выборку по нужным параметрам.